# How to get widgets on blogger Dynamic Views template

Tags: blogger

How to get widgets on blogger Dynamic Views template.
I have blog on blogger.
I can get widgets comments and likeit button from facebook.
When I used blogger on Simple Template I can to get widgets from facebook.
I just use widget's code under  and it worked.
But I don't know how to get that widgets on Dynamic Views Template. 
Where can I use widget's code on Dynamic Views template?
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot show all the widgets in dynamic template, unless for those sidebar one that come open in trnasitions, other normal widgets like custom widgets, ads, fb likes, youtube subscribe are not available on dynamic view template, i faced the similar problem back then, and its only solution is to change to Simple view, or picture window. I am using picture window, http://worldofclashers.blogspot.com/ this is my blog